# intersection about the second category

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category, locally-compact-groups

$G$ is a locally compact Hausdorff topological group, $A$ and $B$ are two Borel subsets of $G$, and  $A$ and $B$ are both of the second category in $G$, then there exist an element $x\in G$, such that $A\bigcap xB$ is of the second category, too.

This problem is too difficult for me. I think for a long time but still cannot solve it out. Help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

We again should use the Baire Property. I recall that a subset $B$ of a topological space $X$ has *the Baire Property* in $X$ if $B$ contains a $G_\delta$-subset $C$ of $X$ such that $B\setminus C$ is meager in $X$. By [Kech, 8.22] each Borel subset of a space $X$ has the Baire Property in $X$. Now we use the following theorem from [Kech].

[image]

Since $A$ and $B$ are both of the second category in $G$, both sets $U(A)$ and $U(B)$ are non-empty. Pick arbitrary elements $a\in U(A)$ and $b\in U(B)$. Put $x=ab^{-1}$. Then a set $C=U(A)\cap xU(B)\ni a$ is an open non-empty set of a locally compact Hausdorff space (which is Baire, for instance, by [Kech, 8.4]). Therefore the set $C$ is of the second category. Then the set  $A\cap xB$ is of the second category too.

*References*

[Kech] A. Kechris. *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, – Springer, 1995.

Comment: Yes, a good answer!  But in that thm 8.29, Let $ {U_{i}} $ be a maximal pairwise disjoint subfamily of {U open...}..." How to choose  ${U_{i}}$? And  why $W$ is dense in $U(A)$? It seems (to be) difficult to me...

Comment: @DavidChan It seems the following. Such a family $\{U_i\}$ can be chosen by Zorn Lemma, :-) and its maximality implies the denseness of the set $W$.

Comment: Can you describe some details in detail?:-) I am not very familiar with Zorn Lemma...

Comment: @DavidChan It seems the following. We use a standard trick. Put $\mathscr U=\{\mathcal U: \mathcal U$ is a pairwise disjoint subfamily of $\{ U$ open: $U\models A\}\}$. It is easy to check if  $\mathscr V\subset \mathscr U$ is a linearly ordered by inclusion, that is for any families $\mathcal U, \mathcal V\in \mathscr V $ holds $\mathcal U\subset \mathcal V$ or $\mathcal V\subset \mathcal U$, then $\bigcup \mathscr V\in \mathscr U$. Then by Zorn lemma there exists a maximal (by inclusion) family $\mathcal U=(U_i)_{i\in I}\in \mathscr U $.